# MongoDB aggregate with lookup and count is slow

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two conditions - one for foreign table, other for primary.

A sample query is

```
db.getCollection('ResourceOrder').aggregate(
    [
    {"$match" : 
            { "$and" : [
                { "Resource.Target.Reference" : { "$eq" : "Organization/93a2f92d-6cc4-41e5-bfef-e9429e70b07b" } },
                { "LastUpdated" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2020-03-06T13:20:33Z") } }] 
            } 
    },
    { "$lookup" : { 
        "from" : "ResourceDiagnosticOrder",
        "localField" : "Resource.Detail.Reference",
        "foreignField" : "Reference",
        "as" : "detail_Lookup" } 
    },
    { "$match" : { "$or" : [{ "detail_Lookup.Resource.Status" : { "$eq" : 3 } }, { "detail_Lookup.Resource.Status" : { "$eq" : 4 } }] } },
    { "$count" : "count" }
    ]
    )
```

The foreign table is ResourceDiagnosticOrder and there is index on the foreign field called Resource

Resource.Target in left table is array if it matters

Please kindly advise, how can I improve it? The search itself takes acceptable time, but the count takes 10+ seconds

What really troubles me is that when I just select all ids from foreign table by the right conditions (that's tens of thousands of ids) and feed them to $in then count works times faster
Is there a way to do an old good inner join?

Comment: First, please understand - $lookup (or any relational activity in any database) is slow.  This is the reason behind having rich data format - you can store all the data for the use case in a single document to avoid a slow lookup.  Having said that, did you verify you have indexes on all key fields (either $match predicates, $lookup predicates, $sort predicates)?

Comment: Yes, all match fields are indexed.
Also no, in relational DB it was impossible to have two selects working faster that one join if the fields are indexed (first select selects IDs, second uses them as filter)
In MongoDB for some reason using giant set of IDs as filter works faster than lookup that includes same query for those IDs

Comment: I would recommend running `explain` on the aggregation to see what the query planner is showing as the execution plan strategy.

Comment: Does putting your $match condition for detail_lookup in a sub-pipeline helps? Ref: https://mongoplayground.net/p/nxz1u6A3sHy

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, tried it just now.
Putting it inside lookup pipeline made search alone for first page (without count) take 13 seconds. With foreignField lookup first page is 0.2 seconds
I'm currently sticking to "pass thousands of ids to find", but more ideas are welcome